# store SID in a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need a way to store the current user's SID in a variable, I tried a lot of variants of:

```
setlocal enableextensions 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ( 
'"wmic path win32_useraccount where name='%UserName%' get sid"'
) do ( 
if not "%%a"==""
set myvar=%%a
echo/%%myvar%%=%myvar% 
pause 
endlocal
```

None are working.

`wmic path win32_useraccount where name='%UserName%' get sid` 
should be returning 3 lines, and I need the second one stored in a variable.

Can someone fix my script?

*Edit*: I am using a .cmd file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('"wmic path win32_useraccount where name='%UserName%' get sid"') do (
   if not "%%a"=="SID" (          
      set myvar=%%a
      goto :loop_end
   )   
)

:loop_end
echo %%myvar%%=%myvar%
```

note the `"delims= "` in the FOR loop. It will separate the input at spaces, that are contained at the end of the output ouf your WMI query.

The condition `if not "%%a"=="SID"` will be true for the second iteration and then assign the variable and break out of the loop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks man, that dit it, sorry for the late reaction, I was to bussy doing other stuff

Answer (score 4):

I write this code and it work good for me

```
for /F "tokens=2" %%i in ('whoami /user /fo table /nh') do set usersid=%%i
```

Comment: I like this, but wouldn't it break if the user name contains a space?

Comment: Also worth noting, whoami processes much faster than wmic.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%s IN ('wmic path win32_useraccount where name^='%username%' get sid /value ^| find /i "SID"') DO SET SID=%%t
```

Comment: Simple and one liner, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another working example of WMIC

```dos
@ECHO OFF
::SET Variables
SET _USERSID=NoValue
SET _User=QueryUserName
::Run the WMIC Command
@FOR /F "SKIP=1" %A IN ('"wmic useraccount where name='%_User%' get sid"') DO @FOR %B IN (%A) DO @SET _USERSID=%B

::Now do something with the SID IF EXISTS
:: Example below
cls
::Advise if the UserID was valid and echo out WMIC results
@IF %_USERSID% == NoValue ECHO     USER ****%_User%**** NOT VALID
@ECHO     WMIC Command %_USERSID%

::Example of using the WMIC %_USERSID% variable for something
@IF NOT %_USERSID% == NoValue REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\%_USERSID%" /F

::SET ECHO Command Prompt ON
@ECHO ON
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopes this will work for you.

```
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('"wmic path win32_useraccount where name='%UserName%' get sid"') do (
   if not "%%a"=="SID" (        
      set myvar=%%a
    goto MESSAGE
   )  
)
goto MESSAGE

echo -----your message---------
```

---

```
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('"wmic path win32_useraccount where name='%UserName%' get sid"') do (
   if not "%%a"=="SID" (        
      set myvar=%%a
    goto MESSAGE
   )  
)
goto MESSAGE

:MESSAGE
echo. 
echo Use this only if all other troubleshooting steps failed. 
echo.
echo and restart the system
set /p yesno=[y/n]
if "%yesno%" equ "y" goto UNINSTALL
if "%yesno%" equ "Y" goto UNINSTALL
if "%yesno%" equ "yes" goto UNINSTALL
if "%yesno%" equ "Yes" goto UNINSTALL
```